# If $X$ is complete and $K$ is relatively compact, then the closure $\overline{K}$ is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Currently I'm self studying functional analysis, namely compact operators. In the text, the author gives the following definitions:

> **Definition 1**: A set $K\subseteq X$ is called a *compact set* if and only if for every sequence $x_n\in K$ there exists an $x\in K$ and a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ of $x_n$ so that $x_{n_k}\to x$.

> **Definition 2**: A set $K\subseteq X$ is called a *relatively compact set* if and only if every sequence $x_n\in K$ has a Cauchy subsequence $x_{n_k}$.

The author then gives the following remark:

> **Remark**: If $X$ is complete and $K$ is relatively compact, then the closure $\overline{K}$ is compact.

I decided to try to show this myself, but I'm having trouble. Any help would be appreciated.

---

My attempt, though unfinished, goes as follows:

*Proof*. Let $x_n\in\overline{K}$. To show that $\overline{K}$ is a compact set we need to show that there exists an $x\in\overline{K}$ and a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ of $x_n$ so that $x_{n_k}\to x$. By defining of the closure operation, $x_n\in \overline{K}$ implies there exists a sequence $y_m\in K$ so that $y_m\to x_n$. Since $K$ is relatively compact, the sequence $y_m$ has a Cauchy subsequence $y_{m_K}$. Since $X$ is complete $y_{m_k}\to x\in\overline{K}$, as $\overline{K}$ is closed.

Comment: Another (more standard?) definition of relatively compact is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relatively_compact_subspace

Comment: @copper.hat . In the context of metric spaces, some authors have used "$K$ is pre-compact" to mean $\overline K$ is compact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument is a little more subtle - the sequence $\{y_m\}$ you construct in the question converges to $x_n$ ($n$ fixed), so you can't use that to get at a subsequence of $\{x_n\}$.

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, since $x_n \in \overline{K}$, there is a point $y_n \in K$ such that $d(y_n,x_n) < 1/n$. Now $\{y_n\}$ has a Cauchy subsequence $\{y_{n_k}\}$. Now, use the triangle inequality to show that $\{x_{n_k}\}$ is also Cauchy.

Comment: Triangle inequality (norm notation):
$$
||x_{n_k}-x_{n_j}||=||x_{n_k}-y_n+y_n-x_{n_j}||\leq||y_n-x_{n_k}||+||y_n-x_{n_j}||<2/n\to0.
$$ Correct? To me, my argument seems off as I don't see where I made use of $\{y_{n_k}\}$ being a Cauchy subsequence...

Comment: What you need is $\|x_{n_k} - x_{n_j}\| \leq \|x_{n_k} - y_{n_k}\| + \|y_{n_k} - y_{n_j}\| + \|y_{n_j} - x_{n_j}\|$.

Comment: Ah okay, I see it now. You're up is very appreciated!

Comment: Just to add, so by the completeness of $X$, there exists an $x\in X$ for which $x_{n_k}\to x$. By the closedness of $\overline{K}$, and $\{x_{n_k}\}\in\overline{K}$, it follows that $x\in\overline{K}$, and hence $\overline{K}$ is compact. Correct?